# How to stop executing a function or action which is in componentwillmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Is there any way stop executing(dispatching) a function or action which is inside in componentwillmount in react test using jest.

I have following code:

```
import {
    resetAutocomplete
} from "../../actions/ui/autocomplete";

class AutocompleteInput extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string,
        tabIndex: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        getSuggestedItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        searchItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        getName: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        selectItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        autocomplete: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        resetAutocomplete: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentWillMount = () => {
        const { resetAutocomplete } = this.props;
        resetAutocomplete();
    };
};
```

and in my test:
test.js

```
const initialState = {
    ui: {
        autocomplete: {
            loading: false,
            search: "test",
            results: [],
            selected: null
        }
    }
};

let persist;
const store = configureStore((persist = false), initialState),
wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AutocompleteInput
          title={"Test"}
          tabIndex={10}
          getSuggestedItem={() => {}}
          searchItem={() => {}}
          getName={() => {}}
          selectItem={() => {}}
        />
    </Provider>
);
```

but in my autocomplete value always reseting due to "resetAutocomplete()". How to avoid this? What am i missing here? I am using jest.

Comment: You can mock resetAutocomplete function and do nothing

Comment: can you please provide an example?